# ajax working when function is on child theme but not in plugin page

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax which passes some jQuery variables to PHP function. My function was supposed to be in a class file. But ajax won't work and shows **bad request**. But if i place php function in my child theme, it works perfectly.

Here is my jQuery AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,                        
      data: {
      action: 'thwec_get_element_block_data',
      block_element_list: block_element_list
    },
     success:function(data){
      alert('success');
      console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(){
      alert('error');
     }
    });
```

And my PHP function.

```
 public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_ajax_thwec_get_element_block_data',array($this,'get_element_block_data')); 

        // $this->get_element_block_data();
        // $this->init_constants();
    }

public function get_element_block_data(){
    var_dump("hello");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in? You'd need to use the [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{$_REQUEST[‘action’]}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv__requestaction/) hook for non-authenticated Ajax actions for logged-out users.

Comment: yes. am logged in. Tired those. But same error

Comment: Are you sure WP has loaded before you init the class?

Comment: yes . sure @Drupalizeme

Comment: Plugin page in dashboard?

Comment: "Bad request" is a 400 status code and usually a server returns that status code when it gets malformed data. What value and format does `block_element_list` have?

Comment: @cybmeta it is an array object . Contains nested arrays and objects

Comment: @MaximSarandi yes .

Comment: Are you sure that `ajaxurl` is defined and present on your admin page?

Comment: i get it when alerting ajaxurl

Comment: Can you try without  `block_element_list`? I'm pretty sure the error can be there, just to be completely sure that it is not the problem.

Comment: tried. Same issue.@cybmeta

Comment: Where is the class being instantiated?

Comment: instance of class is called inside the class and class file included during init

Comment: @JacobPeattie . Thanks for you help. Class instance was created but was not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And i found the answer. As Jacob Peattie asked the instance of the class was defined but was not called. Although the class file was included , instance was not called. Thank you everyone for your valuable time.